# Why is Avagadro's number independent of substance?

Tags: thermodynamics, mole

In the book of Irey, *Thermodynamics*, in vol1, IA, page 4, it is given that

Molecular (atomic) weight $M$:

> The ratio of the mass of a molecule (atom) of a substance to one twelfth of the mass of an atom of the most common isotope of carbon $^{12}\mathrm C$.

Mole:

> A gram mole is the amount of a substance whose mass is equal to its molecular weight in grams. The mass of the one gram mole equals $M$ grams ($M$: molar mass).

Avogadro's number:

> Since the mass of a mole is proportional to molecular weight, there are a definite number of molecules in any molar unit, called $N_\mathrm A$.

And in the remark, the author mentioned that *$N_\mathrm A$ is independent of molar units*, and we know that it is even independent of substance.

However, with these definitions, I cannot understand why $N_\mathrm A$ should be independent of substance.

**Question:**

With these definitions, why is the constant $N_\mathrm A$ independent of substance that is used to measure $N_\mathrm A$?

Comment: It's not related to your actual question, but your book is more than 40 years old. In particular, the concept of "gram mole" is obsolete. You might want to consider getting a new book.

Comment: In short, the constant $N_A$ is independent of substance precisely because it is _defined to be independent of substance_.

Comment: @Loong That is one of the reasons why I particularly have chosen this book, apart from that is a great book; I cannot understand newly written books, regardless of their content.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't see any such statement in the definition; note that you can define something in a way that would be independent of substance, in which case you still show that it is indeed is independent of substance, but what you are claiming is something like "let $N_A$ be a constant that is independent of substance" which is definitely not the case.

Comment: If you cannot see such a statement in the definition then you are looking at the wrong definition

Comment: What is the reason for the down votes ?

Comment: @Waylander How do you exactly justify your claim about that the given definition is wrong ?

Comment: Irey's definitions of mole and molar mass inevitably lead to $N_A$ being a constant. The definition is a bit cumbersome, because only a few weeks ago, $N_A$ has once and forever been defined to be one specific integer number.

Comment: @Karl  how  that lead N_a to be a constant is the main question, so an explanaion would be nice

Comment: Your "gram mole" Isn't mole! Mole is exactly Avogadro's number of anything! Loong comment is actually exactly the point of your miunderstanding...

Comment: @Mithoron Would you care to give an explanation why it is the case, or will you just state it and done with it ?

Comment: ;/ There is one single specific proportion between atomic mass unit and gram and it's Avogadro's number.

Comment: @Mithoron How do you know that ? If you can explain that, you basically will be answering to my main question.

Comment: @Mithoron Plus, how does that explain the claim that "a gram mole is not a mole" ?

Comment: "Gram mole" is an archaic unit name. By Irey's definition, it is identical to the mole as defined in the SI system half a century ago.

Answer (score 13):

It is the same reason that a dozen doesn't depend on whether you are counting grapes or elephants. That is how the mole is defined: it is a number, nothing else.

The confusion, I suspect, is because of how we *measure* that number (or, strictly, how we originally measured it as the definition changed recently). The intention of the unit was always to define a number of things independent of the thing being measured. But to measure that number chemists originally defined it as the count of atoms in a particular substance (originally on <sup>16</sup>O and later <sup>12</sup>C). Since November 2018 it is now defined as an exact number.

Presumably something similar happened as humanity learned to count beyond 10. To illustrate the concept of 12 they might have used 12 rocks or 12 wildebeest. But the idea of a dozen was independent of the things being counted: the things were merely a concrete illustration or example of the idea of a dozen. Same with the mole: the thing being counted is irrelevant even if you had to use a concrete example of counting the atoms in a real substance to illustrate the number.

Comment: So, If understand correctly, we experimentally found that this number was independent of the substance, and then defined it in a way which also described how to measure that number ? and this is the main confusion; there is nothing that forces that quantity be independent of substance, but it is an experimental fact that it is the case ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas No. The *definition* is not empirical. Chemists observed that things combine in fixed ratios long before they even had a concept of the atom. As the concept of the atom emerged, chemists wanted to count them. Then they developed the concept of the mole and needed to measure how many atoms were in it. Don't confuse the number (independent of what is being measured) with how it was first counted. A dozen is not an empirical concept depending on what thing we are counting: it is an abstract number.

Comment: "Don't confuse the number (independent of what is being measured)"; yes the definition does not specify any specific substance, but it might turn out that measuring that number for different substances result in different numbers. In that sense, the definition might not be even well defined (in the mathematical sense); that is why somehow, empirically or analytically we should show that that number is independent of the substance that is being measured.

Comment: For example, in your example of "dozen": we are explicitly defining dozen as a number of things, which is indeed independent of the substance since it is defined as a number; but in the $N_A$ case, the definition includes mass of the substance and its molecular weight, which are specific to the substance that is being measured.

Comment: @onurcanbektas You are missing the point. A mole has always been a number and is currently *defined* as a precise number. Initially chemists used specific substances to measure it but the *definition* didn't change because of the difficulty of measuring it. in fact, if a measurement of a different substance looked off, what chemists would change is the atomic mass not the count of moles.

Comment: @onurcanbektas a dozen is *exactly* the same sort of concept as the mole. The only issue is that counting a mole using your fingers is a lot harder. We don't need to check empirically that a dozen elephants had the same number of things in it as a dozen grapes. Replace *dozen* with *moles* and the grapes and elephants with different atoms and the sentence still works exactly the same way.

Comment: Matt, the number of people in a room is also a number, but it is dependent on which room are we talking about. You mentioned that in order to make it independent, they  change the atomic mass, but that change is still not arbitrary, like changing the atomic mass of He, but not H; a single definition works of atomic mass works for every atom, so there is question still remains why does (with the current definition of atomic mass of atoms) the avagadro's number defined as in the question independent of substance that is being measured.

Comment: @onurcanbektas The number of moles of a chemical in a test tube depends on the size of the test tube, as the number of people in a room depends on how big the room is. How we count the people does not nor does our definition of people. We measure atomic mass of a substance *assuming* we know how much (in moles) of that substance there is. The idea that substances are made of discrete units is an *axiom* of the atomic theory of matter not something we need to keep testing empirically. The mole is just how we count those units.

Comment: "the number of people in a room depends on how big the room is" really ? So you haven't seen an empty room whose size is nonzero ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas I assumed your point was that the room was as packed as possible with people. It is clearly possible that a room doesn't contain as many people as that. But it is people we are counting, not the floor area of the room, so my point stands.

Comment: @onurcanbektas You are veering off into persistent ignorance and rudeness. A mole is a certain number of things, there is probably not a mole of stars in the sky, there is a little bit more than a mole of water in a half full glass, there is exactly a mole of electrons in half a mole of hydrogen gas. Same as there are usually not a dozen pups to the dog, usually more than a dozen children in a regular sized 5th grade class and exactly a dozen in a 12 pack of eggs. a mole is a mole by definition, exactly 1 per atom in a **dozen** grammes of carbon atoms. https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/

Comment: Technically, "dozen" is just "two and ten".  It cones from a French word for "twelve" which, in turn, they derived from the Latin for "two and ten".

Comment: @StianYttervik have read the whole question by the way ? Note that my purpose is to learn, not to be rude; i think you guys get offended to quickly, which is not healthy in an academic discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the $\ce{^9_4Be}$ isotope and apply the definitions:

**Relative atomic mass**

The relative atomic mass of $\ce{^{12}C}$ is, by definition, 12. Looking at the periodic table, we find that the relative atomic mass of beryllium is 9.0121831(5). That makes sense because $\ce{^{12}C}$ has a mass number of 12 (6 protons and 6 neutrons) while beryllium has a mass number of only 9 (4 protons and 5 neutrons).

**Mass of one mole of substance**

According to the definition, one mole of beryllium has a mass of 9.0121831(5) g, just as one mole of $\ce{^{12}C}$ has a mass of 12 g (exactly, until May 20th 2019). These two samples have same number of particles because their mass ratios are equal to their relative atomic mass ratios (look back at the definition of the relative atomic mass, it relates one atom of beryllium to one atom of carbon-12).

**Avogadro constant $N_\mathrm A$**

A mole of anything contains the same number of particles as a mole of $\ce{^{12}C}$. This follows from combining the definitions of relative atomic mass and of the unit mole (pre May 20th, 2019). The Avogadro constant is the ratio of number of particles to amount of substance:

$$ N_\mathrm A = \frac{N_\text{particles}}{n_\text{sample}}$$

Before May 20th, 2019, the Avogadro constant was experimentally determined. You would have to count atoms in a sample of known chemical amount, typically indirectly. For example, if you know the mass, the radius, the atomic distances of a silicon sphere and the average molar mass of the silicon sample, you could figure out the Avogadro constant.

Since May 20th, 2019, the Avogadro constant is set to a constant value:

$$ N_\mathrm A = \pu{6.02214076e23 mol-1}$$

Your textbook is out of date, just like most textbooks were when you asked your question, which does not make sense anymore given the current definition of the Avogadro constant.

Comment: I understood why their mass ratios are equal to their relative atomic mass ratios; however, how does that imply that both samples have the same number of particles ?

Comment: The mass ratio of one atom Be to one atom C is 9 to 12. If I compare a million atoms of Be to a million atoms of C, the mass ratio will be 9 to 12. Conversely, if the mass ratio is 9 to 12, I will have the same number of atoms of Be and C, no matter what the absolute mass is.

Comment: You mean the _same number of atoms of Be relative to C_ ?

Comment: Yes, in order to get the same number of atoms of Be relative to the number of atoms in a C sample, their masses must have the ratio of 9 to 12.